# Returned char* array from function prints incorrect values (probably memory management)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, char

I'm working on a function that will take in a file, line by line, and take each line, remove anything that isn't hex from it, and return the non-hex free line.  As I'm iterating through each line of the file I'm seeing the expected values, and the function is only grabbing the hex values, which is exactly what I want.

However, when I print the `strippedLine` in the main, I'm getting some unexpected characters at the beginning, and missing the last byte of data.  (I'm very new to c, and memory management).

Here's code from my main:

```
char currentLine[100];
char *strippedLine = NULL;

FILE *file = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

// Works as expected getting each line from file.
while(fgets(currentLine, sizeof(currentLine), file) != NULL)
{   
    // Change from original question
    //strippedLine = (char *)malloc(1 + strlen(currentLine));
    strippedLine = malloc(1 + strlen(currentLine));

    // Change from original question
    //strcpy(strippedLine, StripNonHex(currentLine));
    strippedLine = StripNonHex(currentLine);


    printf("%s", strippedLine);

}
```

Here's the function that I'd like to return a char array with all hex stripped out:

```
char *StripNonHex(char *line)
{
    char *nl = NULL;
    char *token = NULL;                        
    int convs = 0;
    unsigned ch = '\0';
    int hexLine = 0;
    char *strippedLine = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    int counter = 0;

    // Remove new-line char
    if (nl)                                                                  
    {                                                                                                              
        *nl = '\0';                              
    }                                                                                                                                      
    // Split each line into space-delimited tokens
    token = strtok(line, " ");

    convs = sscanf(token, "%x", &ch);

    // Works as expected seeing each space delimited hex value of file.
    while(token)
    {
        convs = sscanf(token, "%x", &ch);
        if (convs == 1 && strlen(token) == 2)
        {
            hexLine = 1;
            strippedLine[counter] = token;
        }
        counter += strlen(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        // Removed from original question
        //counter++;
    }

    // Removed from original question
    //strippedLine[counter + 1] = '\0';

    return strippedLine;
}
```

---

Sorry about missing the input and output.  Here it is below

**Input**

```
A5 12 00 24 00 01 22 00 3F 11
```

**Output**

```
≡¡║A5120024000122003F
```

This output is much closer thanks to the recommendations from @Barmar.  It's just missing the last byte, and has some unexpected characters in the beginning.

I've updated my question to make more sense with what I have now.

---

Moving `counter += strlen(token);` inside of the `if` statement was my final issue.  I was inadvertently moving my pointer whether I found what I was looking for or not.

Comment: Can you give at least one example of an input, the output you got, and the output you expected?

Comment: `strippedLine[counter + 1] = '\0';` Try changing to `strippedLine[counter] = '\0';`

Comment: Without knowing what is in `line`, there is not much anybody can do except guess at where your failures are likely to be.

Comment: Enable your compiler warnings and read all messages carefully. Never ignore anything. What do you think this line `strippedLine[counter] = token;` does?

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: `convs = sscanf(token, "%x", &ch);` just tells you if the token begins with hex characters, it doesn't ensure that the whole token is hex. Also, `ch` should be declared `unsigned int`.

Comment: I made some changes based on @Barmar answer.  I've added the input and output I'm getting.  I'll go through the other suggestions made here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not copying `token` into `strippedLine` correctly.

```
strippedLine[counter] = token;
```

converts the pointer in `token` to a `char`, which is an implementation-defined conversion, most likely just taking the low-order 8 bits of the address, and stores that converted value into `strippedLine[counter]`. The correct way is:

```
strcpy(&strippedLine[counter], token);
```

Then you need to increment `counter` by the length of the token:

```
counter += strlen(token);
```

If you want to scan a hex value into `unsigned char`, you need to use:

```
sscanf(token, "%hhx", &ch);
```

You don't need `strippedLine[counter + 1] = '\0';` at the end, since `strcpy()` copies the null terminator.

Since `StripNonHex()` returns a newly allocated string, there's no need to use `strcpy()` on the result. Just assign it directly the `strippedLine` instead of allocating another string.

```
char *strippedLine = StripNonHex(currentLine);
```

Then you'll be able to use `free(strippedLine)` when you're done with the line.

`StripNonHex()` should use `strlen()` when allocating its `strippedLine` variable, rather than hard-coding the size `256`.

```
char *strippedLine = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've updated the question to show what's happening now. I have a few questions about suggestions you made, but I'm going to look over them for a bit before I ask.  Thanks again.  (I'll mark this as answer once I understand all of it)

Comment: I think the only question I have left with your answer is about the ```%hhx``` addition.  When I change the type of ```ch``` to ```unsigned int``` and add the ```%hhx```, I get an error ```Parameter type mismatch; expecting pointer to char but found pointer to int```.   Even if I change the type of convs and *token to match, I get the same error.

Comment: You either change the type of `ch` to `unsigned int`, or you change the `sscanf` format to `%hhx`. You don't do both.

Comment: The type of `convs` is unrelated to this.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help.  I understand all of your recommended changes, and it's all working as expected now.